# Python-3.6 - "Not In List" Error

Tags: python-3.6

I'm using Python 3.6.3.

I am trying to validate a username and password from a csv file. The usernames and subsequent passwords are on new lines in the text file, so when appended to an empty array I called "up" it was turned into a 2d array with each line a list within "up". I ask the user for a username and a password. So then I tried to use a for loop (*for x in up*) to loop over each list in up via *up[up.index(x)]*, and then used *.index(username)* straight afterwards in a variable called j (*j = up[up.index(x)].index(username)*). The code will be given, with the section I'm having trouble with highlighted.
These are the contents of the csv file: [Text File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/16eRw.png)

When I run the code the it returns an error that says the ***username in not in the list.*** I've searched for answers but couldn't find anything. Is there something that I've overlooked?

Any help will be gratefully appreciated.

```
import csv

validoption = ["i","u"]

while True:

    option = input("Sign in or sign up\nPlease enter 'i' to sign in or 'u' to sign up: ")
    if option in validoption:
        if option is "i":
            with open("login.txt","r") as l:
                up = []
                read = csv.reader(l)
                count = 0
                for line in read:
                    up.append(line)
                    count=+1
                invalid = True
                while invalid:
                    username = input("Please enter your username: ")
                    password = input("Please enter your password: ")
                    if [[y is username for y in x] for x in up]:
                        for x in up:
                            j = up[up.index(x)].index(username)
                            if password in up[up.index(x)][j+1]:
                                invalid = False
                            else:
                                print("Password is incorrect")
                    else:
                        print("Username is not recognised")
        else:
            with open("login.txt","a") as l:
                username = input("Please enter your username: ")
                while True:
                    password = input("Please enter your password\nPlease make sure that your password is longer than 8 characters, has a capiatal letter and a number: ")
                    if len(password)<8:
                        if any(p.isupper() for p in password):
                            if any(p.isdigit() for p in password):
                                break
                            else:
                                print("Password must have one number in it\n")
                        else:
                            print("Password must have one capital letter\n")
                    else:
                        print("Password must have more than 8 charaters")
                userdetails = username+","+password
                l.write(userdetails)
                l.write("\n")
```

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`y is username` tests if the two values are the *same* object, not equivalent objects. Use `==` instead.

Additionally, you should consider using the username as the key of a `dict`, then you can use `in` and eliminate some of the loops in your application code.

Comment: I turned 'up' into a dictionary with the username as a key and the passwords as their 'definitions'. This worked. Thank you very much :))))